# Open a file using package name of third party app

Tags: android

I want to open a file let's say xxx.pdf in specific viewer. I am getting the information of viewer using

```
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = activity.getPackageManager()
                                            .queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

ResolveInfo gives me the complete information of supported viewer. From there I get package name , activity etc.

Now I want to launch the file using package name. I am trying following code.

```
Intent supportedAppIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
       supportedAppIntent.setAction(ACTION_VIEW);
       supportedAppIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), contentType);
       activity.startActivity(supportedAppIntent);
```

But It only opens the application , not the file.

Comment: Probably issue is intent-filter is not resolving. so first check using IntentChooser app is appearing or not in available apps list which is able to open view pdf file type

Comment: App is available , as I am getting it from queryIntentAcitivities() , I can get all the details , App is also launching. But the issue is , It doesn't open file. Ideally App should be launched by opening file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Missing line was `intent.setClassName(packageName, className);`

className you can get it from `resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;`

Below is the complete code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setClassName(packageName, classname);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), contentType);
                activity.startActivity(supportedAppIntent);
```